# Partial update in Ember-Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Imagine a bug tracker.

Each ticket contains a lot of data. Now the status of a few tickets from a long list of tickets is updated.

```
App.Ticket = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    status: DS.attr('string'),
    ...
});
```

Currently when invoking `save` in ember-data this would send the complete models to the server.

**What can I do to only send a partial update, like `[{"id": 1, "status": "closed"}, {...}]`?**

*PS: I understand that this is not possible right now, so I'm wondering if there is a workaround / modification that would enable this? (a general-purpose solution is not required).*

Comment: HTTP spec has a PATCH verb that is for exactly this (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789). We'd just need ember-data to support it. I definitely +1 this request!

Answer (score 3):

My current workaround is to specify a `readOnly` option that excludes the attributes that I don't want to be sent in the POST.

Details can be found here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/303#issuecomment-13993905

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into this as well and if you want this to apply to *all* saves, then today you would fix it with a serializer like `serializers/ticket.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    status: {serialize: false}
  }
});
```

This would strip out `status`.